# Get road type (clazz) in osm2po

Tags: java, osm2po

Can I get clazz of a segment in Java? For example,

```
RoutingResultSegment rrs = graph.lookupSegment(path[j])
```

How can I get `rrs`'s clazz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rrs.getFlags()
```

returns a user defined 32 Bit Integer which contains the configured road type by default.
You can override this beavior if needed. In order to save memory it always returns 0.
To activate it open the graph with e.g.

```
Graph graph = new Graph(graphFile, new Log(), Graph.SUPPORT_EDGEFLAGS);
```

Comment: Thanks! To use `findClosestVertexId`, I also needed `Graph.SUPPORT_LATLON`. Are javadocs available?

Comment: Not online and not in english (only in german ;-( Nevertheless I've already sent the java-docs (routing part only) to some people via mail. So if you need it, please contact me via email.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know German. I have one more problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/what-does-findcloseedges-do-in-osm2po Variable names are generic in `findCloseEdges` so I am not sure what the third argument is.

Comment: I just answered it ;-)