# What does `findCloseEdges` do in osm2po?

Tags: java, osm2po

I have something like this:

```
int[] edges = graph.findCloseEdges(lat, lon, 1); // returns only one element
RoutingResultSegment rrs = graph.lookupSegment(edges[0]);
LatLon[] latlons = rrs.getLatLons()
```

For the red dot in the image (with `lat`/`lon`), array `latlons` contains the blue points. I would instead expect "close edge" to be a segment of the A3/E70 road.

Here is [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4uO7.png) (I don't have enough reputation to post images apparently).

What is the third integer argument in `findCloseGraph` and what does this method return? I need to do simple "snap to road".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this is a very expert question ;-)

```
graph.findCloseEdges(lat, lon, x)
```

finds x close Edges that are not necessarily the closest ones.
What you are going to find is clear.
Use TouchPoint.create(...) instead.