# Get road type (clazz) is osm2po 5.0.0

Tags: osm2po

I looked into using getFlags() for this as described here,
[Get road type (clazz) in osm2po](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/get-road-type-clazz-in-osm2po)
but for some reason I'm getting 65551 instead of 15, and 65557 instead of 21. Seems like if I unset the 16th bit, I get the right value (rrs.getFlags() & ~(1 << 16)). Is there some significance to that 16th bit, and would there be some other bits set? Do we just take the lower 16 bits? I'm using osm2po 5.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsible for the value U receive is the DefaultGraphBuildInterceptor.
The current implementation does the following:

```
@Override
public int getFlags(SegmentedWay way, int segmentIdx, boolean reverse) {
    Node[] nodes = way.getSegments()[segmentIdx].getNodes();
    Node targetNode = reverse ? nodes[0] : nodes[nodes.length -1];
    int wayClazz = way.getClazz() & 0xFF;
    int nodeClazz = targetNode.getClazz() & 0xFF;
    int wayFlags = way.getFlags() & 0xFF;
    int wayInternFlags = way.getInternFlags() & 0xFF;

    int flags = wayInternFlags << 24 | wayFlags << 16 | nodeClazz << 8 | wayClazz;
    return flags;
}
```

meaning, a simple cast to (byte) returns the road class, e.g. motorway, tertiary etc.
But if you'd like to encode it your way, feel free to overwrite the method above and inject your own implementation of GraphBuildInterceptor in the config.